# Make "cookie" a synonym of "cookies"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both [cookie](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookie) and [cookies](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookies) were used in questions. Should not they be merged, and [cookie](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookie) made a synonym of [cookies](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I set this up so [cookies](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookies) is main and [cookie](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookie) is a synonym.